# Remote XCode flow with NativeScript

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript

In Cordova I know it is possible to have a remote XCode location setup to compile iOS apps and get the binary back.

Explained [here](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/) using Visual Studio.

So what I want to know is, can it be done with NativeScript?

Thanking you all in advance.

Comment: you could use Telerik Platform - http://www.telerik.com/platform#overview to develop application for both iOS and Android platforms. There is free trial version. You could develop app for iOS without having Mac.

Comment: Dear @nikolay, 

I read about that as well, but sadly there is no way to use XCode remote service except by hacking it in yourself? <-- If I manage this I will share in the git repo don't worry. ;)

Also to be honest I find the prices steep as there is the billed annually upfront business. Which means 12 * $39 = $468 for a single user! I might be even able to find a second hand Mac machine for that to do the compiling. :D